# [php]how to get only text inside <tag> and build it to array

Tags: php

Here I have text that read from file.txt like this (no close tag)

[HEAD]

[TITLE-MAIN]

example news1

[TITLE-SUB]

title sub1

[CONTENT]

content text1

[HEAD]

[TITLE-MAIN]

example news2

[TITLE-SUB]

title sub2

[CONTENT]

content text2

[HEAD]

...

---

I would like to make array look like this 
 and array key split by [HEAD] tag

```
[0] => array(
'TITLE-MAIN' => 'example news1',
'TITLE-SUB' => 'title sub1',
'CONTENT' => 'content text1'),

[1] => array(
'TITLE-MAIN' => 'example news2',
'TITLE-SUB' => 'title sub2',
'CONTENT' => 'content text2')
```

Comment: "_I would like to make array look like this_" Have you done anything to get where you want? If so, please post the code (in your question, _not_ the comments). Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it. Use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to split your text into sections around the `[HEAD]` tag, then again to split each section into tags. Then it's just a matter of putting the tag name together with its contents into an array:

```
$text = '[HEAD]

[TITLE-MAIN]

example news1

[TITLE-SUB]

title sub1

[CONTENT]

content text1


[HEAD]

[TITLE-MAIN]

example news2

[TITLE-SUB]

title sub2

[CONTENT]

content text2';

$sections = array();
foreach (preg_split('/\s*\[HEAD\]\s*/', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) as $section) {
    $s = trim($section);
    $tag_data = preg_split('/\[([^\]]+)\]/', $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($tag_data); $i += 2) {
        $tags[$tag_data[$i]] = trim($tag_data[$i+1]);
    }
    $sections[] = $tags;
}
print_r($sections);
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [TITLE-MAIN] => example news1 
        [TITLE-SUB] => title sub1
        [CONTENT] => content text1
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [TITLE-MAIN] => example news2
        [TITLE-SUB] => title sub2
        [CONTENT] => content text2
    ) 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/347Pu)

Comment: i have write code for this but your code is minimum and good optimize code. nice +1

Comment: @BilalAhmed thanks - just using the tools PHP already gave us. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can used `explode` function with `foreach`.

Here is the code.

```
<?php

function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {

    $ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
    $launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
    return  $launch;
}

$text = file_get_contents('your_file.txt');


//$exploded = multiexplode(array("[","]"),$text);
$exploded=explode('[HEAD]', $text);
echo "<pre>";
// print_r($exploded);
// exit;
$data = array();
$count=0;
foreach ($exploded as $key => $value) {
    $multi_explode=multiexplode(array("[","]"),$value);

    foreach ($multi_explode as $key1 => $value1) {
        if($value1=='TITLE-MAIN'){
            $data[$count]['TITLE-MAIN']=trim($multi_explode[$key1+1]);
        }
        if($value1=='TITLE-SUB'){
            $data[$count]['TITLE-SUB']=trim($multi_explode[$key1+1]);
        }
        if($value1=='CONTENT'){
            $data[$count]['CONTENT']=trim($multi_explode[$key1+1]);
        }
    }
    $count++;


}
    print_r($data);


?>
```

you can check the desired [output here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/587e484f8c423f71de16c830208f42356a1de118)